# No module named pip and get-pip.py issue

Tags: python, pip

I heard that python3 comes with pip so i tried some packages from requirements.txt in the shell prompt but it gave me No module named pip even when trying to install from get-pip.py it gives me a error something like python 2.7 but i have python3!
does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When you run `get-pip.py`, use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Please show output from `python --version`

Answer (score 0):

Using this on cmd, you'll get pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Here more info:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/

Comment: i did and got ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.

Comment: Then I think it would be easier if you download that file into your machine(https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py) and run it with python

Comment: i got 22.2.2 but i tried to install the required packages, but got 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Here you wild find more info: https://www.pythonpip.com/python-tutorials/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: Why are we assuming OP is running Unix machine (or has curl installed)?